# Checkbox is underlined in red, but I’ve checked everything ten times. Can someone help me?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

```
Container(
    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
        horizontal: 22
    ),
    child:
    ListTile(
      leading: Checkbox(value: false,),
      title: Text('Tomate',
        style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 18.0,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
            color: Colors.orangeAccent),
      ),
      trailing: Icon(Icons.delete_outline),
    ),
  ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Checkbox` requires an `onChanged` argument. :-)

Comment: How do I do that? Sorry, I’m new.

Comment: Did it solve the main issue you were having - or was it just an additional problem?

Comment: If this solved your problem then please accept the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you have an active `Scaffold` widget on the screen you're working on?

If you don't, you may have this kind of result, and it may explain the layout you're facing.

[image]

Comment: Yes, I have. Shall I send you everything?

Comment: yes, please update your post add images and minimal code for reproduction

Comment: I am so sorry! The Checkbox is underlined in red.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your Container with Material widget.

```
Material(
  child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
              horizontal: 22
          ),
          child:
            ListTile(
              leading: Checkbox(value: false,),
              title: Text('Tomate',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 18.0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                color: Colors.black54),
              ),
            trailing: Icon(Icons.delete_outline),
            ),
        ),
),
```

Comment: I am so sorry! The Checkbox is underlined in red.

Comment: CheckBox requires onChanged and value property. check you add them.
CheckBox(
  onChanged: (value){},
  value: your_variable,
)